# ERROR Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema

Tags: node.js

I am using node.js and webpack for the first time and I got this weird error. I am using node.js `version 10.15.3`. I also tried using nodejs `version 12.0.0` but I got the same error.

Here is my webpack config file:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    mode: 'development'
}
```

Comment: *and I got this weird error* ... But what error?

Comment: could you write a command that you are using for running Webpack?

Comment: The error is on the title.

Comment: I used following command for installing webpack.
    npm install webpack --save-dev